# Make table with varying width per column keeping the overall width of table constant in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, css, gridview

I want different width for different column.I have specified the width of the particular column but the width is equal to the width of the text.I checked if the css is reachable by appying background-color and it works.But no matter how much width i give its width is equal to the width of the text.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
        <ItemStyle CssClass="imgclass" />
            <EditItemTemplate> 
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbimage" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("imag")%>' /> 
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblimage" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("imag")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And its css is:

```
.imgclass
{
background-color:green;
width:120px;
overflow:hidden;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply max-width and min-width.The max-width property dosen't allow the cell to have width more then the value you specify.

In your case this should work.

```
.imgclass
{
max-width:120px;
background-color:green;
overflow:hidden;  
}
```